# Java DataOutputStream not sending data to sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I have a java application which uses sockets to communicate with another computer. I´m using a DataOutputStream to write data to the server and a BufferedReader to read from server. Before reaching the problem, I can succesfully send and read responses several times from the server.

However there´s a part where I send two, `writeBytes()` functions one after the other. At this point, my server just reads the first string and stays stuck on `readline()` even though I´ve send another string on the second `writeBytes()`.

Here´s my snippet:

```
InetAddress ipServer = InetAddress.getByName(direcciones.get(0).host);
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ipServer,25);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
String response = inFromServer.readLine();
```

Here is where I´m getting just the email.data String and not the "." that comes afterwards.

```
outToServer.writeBytes(email.data+"\r\n");
outToServer.writeBytes("."+ "\r\n");
response = inFromServer.readLine();
```

This is how the data is read on the server:

```
while(mailReady == false){
    String linea;
    linea = input.readLine();
    System.out.println("INPUT Paso5: "+linea);
    email.data += linea+"\n";

    if(linea.equals(".")){
        mailReady = true;
        ...
```

Where input is a BufferedReader.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Instead of `DataOutoutStream.writeBytes()` you should be using `BufferedWriter.write()` followed by `BufferedWriter.newline().`

Comment: I changed to the BufferedWriter using write and newline() but I´m still getting the same problem. Also, I do write lines because of the "\r\n" on the string I send.

Comment: So why did you mark this answer as correct then?